# How can i get count from query post

Tags: query-posts, wp-query

How can i get the row counts in query post like mysql count(*).

```
$obj_name = new WP_Query($args);

while ($obj_name->have_posts()) : $obj_name->the_post(); 

// here i want to predict looping counts

endwhile;
```

How can i do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$num = $obj_name->post_count;
```

Reference: [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: This does not actually answer the question - `post_count` will return the total number of posts being shown on the current page.

Answer (score 57):

The accepted answer here is wrong which is also confirmed in my situation.
Please, compare from the referenced page:

> **$post_count** The number of posts being displayed.
>
> **$found_posts** The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters

This way, $post_count will show, for example, number of posts per page if there are more than one page of results. Only if total number is less than number of results per page it will match total amount.

The correct method to get total results number is:

`$obj_name->found_posts`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

To get the total number of posts WP_Query returns use "found_posts"

Here is the example -

```
        <?php 
           $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'post'
           );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $totalpost = $the_query->found_posts; 
        ?>
```

Use your custom post type name in place of 'post', you can also pass the category id too ( 'cat' => 4,)

Comment: Watch out if you use `posts_per_page` in your query, this will return the total post count regardless of page size