# Get ONLY the count from wp_query without fetching posts

Tags: wp-query

This is potentially a duplicate but what was listed on the following link didn't work for me : [Return only Count from a wp_query request?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177908/return-only-count-from-a-wp-query-request)

I can't get the count using the query below. If I set `posts_per_page = -1` it renders a blank page, if I set it to something like 10, it returns 10 found_posts..

There's 190k results with "special_key", so maybe something to do with it..?

```
// There are 190k records with post_meta "special_key" on each coupon/post.
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
    'meta_key' => 'special_key',  
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'no_found_rows' => true,    
);

$results = new WP_Query($query);
echo $results->found_posts; //// This is 0...
echo $results->count_posts; //// This is 0...
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If it helps, I'm running the query from inside a plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get count from query post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23557/how-can-i-get-count-from-query-post)

Comment: Disagree, the  $results->found_posts is in there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `found_posts` property of the `WP_Query` class is what you're looking for, which is the amount of found posts for the *current* query. However, you got a `0` because you set `no_found_rows` (in the `$query` array) to `true`, which means the amount there will not be calculated. I.e.

- WordPress will not append `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to the SQL command for querying the posts. Otherwise, the command would be something like: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS {the rest of the query}`
- WordPress will not execute `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` *after* the posts query is complete. And when it's not executed, the value of the `found_posts` property would be a zero (`0`).

So remove the `no_found_rows` from the `$query` array, and the `$results->found_posts` would have the proper value:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
    'meta_key' => 'special_key',
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
```

Comment: But I have no_found_rows set to true? I'll give that exact copy paste a try and report back.

Comment: Lol sorry, that `false` was a typo. I've corrected it. (and previously added more details)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I REALLY wish the documentation used your explanation. That makes sense and it worked. The biggest confusion was the no_found_rows, setting it to true or false actually messed with the query, omitting it helped, alongside ids.

Comment: Setting `no_found_rows` to `false` should also work, although I wouldn't set `no_found_rows` if I were to set its value to `false` since that's the default value. Anyway, I'm glad the answer helped you. =)